# What do the medal icons at the top of the catch screen mean?

Tags: pokemon-go

So, maybe these have always been there, but I just noticed that at the top of my catch screen, I briefly see tiny icons that look like the medals.
What purpose do they serve (other than identifying which categories the pokemon would fall into)?

I tried clicking on them, but nothing happened. I just wondered if I might be missing out on something?

Comment: They were added in the most recent update to the game.

Answer (score 14):

They are there to notify you that the Pokémon you are attempting to catch is affected by one (or two) medals that you have achieved from catching 10, 50, or 200 Pokémon of the same type.

It is currently unknown exactly what these medals' +1/2/3 bonuses do, but they do improve capture rate *somehow*.

The updated medal functionality is new as of Android version 0.42.2 and iOS version 1.11.2.